# How to communicate between two microservices databases?

Tags: database, microservices

I am new to microservice architecture, I have two different services like **Users** and **Computers**. Where we can create users separately and store in users database, we can add computers separately to computers database. It is also possible to link user to a computer. What is the best way to store the **UserComputers** data and How to update the individual databases data if there is some update?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just store the user data in the computers database. Solved. Do not worry about duplication of data. Data duplication is the cost of using microservices.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new microservice architecture, each service should be entirely responsible for its own data. This allows you to evolve each service independently without leaking implementation details outside the service.

The Computers service could expose an identifier for each computer that external services can use to make a connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so if **computer service expose an identifier for each computer** where to store the data like we assigned a computer to a user. I meant should we store in Users service or Computers service or do we need to create the separate service for this?

Comment: It is really up to you how small you want to create your services. But something to consider is how many people should work on each service. If alot of logic belongs together with the relation between a user and a computer then perhaps it would make sense to add a service just for that. But if not then I suggest adding it to the service where it makes the most sense. But dont share internal ids between the two microservices. Then it will be hard to migrate the data later if you want to pull it to another service.